# If R is not an equivalence relation, then its classes do not form a partition?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

True or false: if X is a set and R is a relation on X which is not an equivalence relation,
then

{[x]R : x ∈ X}
is not a partition of X.

After some fruitless efforts, it dawned on me to take the contrapositive: If {[x]R : x ∈ X} is a partition of X, then R is an equivalence relation on X.

Is this indeed the contrapositive statement, and, if so, is its proof any easier than that of the original statement? Because I wasn't making any progress with that.

Comment: The definition we were given in the lectures is exactly this: Let R be a relation on a set X. We define {[x]R : x ∈ X} to be: {y in X: xRy}

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the contrapositive.

However, the statement is *false*:
Consider $X=\{1,2\}$ and $R:=\{(1,2),\ (2,1)\}$. Then we have $[1]R=\{2\}$ and $[2]R=\{1\}$ which clearly makes a partition.

Comment: I see...unfortunately, my gut feeling was telling me that the statement was true, hence my endeavors to prove it true. Thanks!